# how to get text from a http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http

How do I get the text off of a http api that I built? So I built a http api like this http://IPADDRESS/getText/hkjfskhfkjdshfkj and it responds "HI" or something like that, so my question is how do I call the api then read it in to a varible on my webpage using javascript?

Also the server is written in nodejs.

Comment: You built an HTTP API in Node, and you don't know how to read from the request..? That can't be it. What are you trying to read? POST body? GET params? Path name?

Comment: Show us the code you're using to call the API and we can show you were the response is in that code.  Is it Ajax from a browser?  Called from some other server?

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry I guess I made this unclear but what I am asking is how to call the http api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either make a [Rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) Service, or you just make a [regular expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) that filters your wanted part out of your url from `window.location.href`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with an ajax request.

Example with jQuery:

```
var someVariable = ""; // variable is empty at start

$.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url:  'http://IPADDRESS/getText/hkjfskhfkjdshfkj'
      }).done( function (responseText) {
                // responseText contains 'HI'or something like that
                someVariable = responseText;
                alert(someVariable);
      });
```